# Matrixes in contiguous position of memory

Tags: c

I often use to memorize all matrixes in a single vector, because my book says it's faster to use a single vector.And the access to a matrix is slower in time.
If I have a code like this one:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int mat[10][10],i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        mat[i][0]=99;
    int *ptr=&mat[0][0];
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",*ptr);
        ptr+=10;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to run it 4/5 times and all times prints 10 times 99.
So also matrixes are memorized in contigous positions of memory? Always?
If yes, why the access to a vector is faster?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'matrix' and 'vector'?  I've answered as best I can, but I'm just guessing what you mean based on your example program.

Comment: 2D arrays and 1D arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, arrays (in C) are stored in contiguous memory, and since that your `mat` is array of arrays, it also stored in a contiguous memory. I think that dereferencing by one index (when you have some separating 1D arrays) may be a little faster than dereferencing by two indexes (in matrix), but the difference is too small to worry about.

Comment: If you're going to emulate a 2D array with a 1D array, you're going to need to calculate the index anyway.  Whether you do it explicitly or the compiler does it seems like it probably doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I understood from the question, that he have some unrelated 1D arrays, and he wants to emulate them by one 2D array. In that case, the compiler may not calculate the first index. (think about vla)

Answer (score 2):

If by 'matrix' you mean two-dimensional array, then yes they're in contiguous memory.  2D arrays in C are just arrays of arrays (row major).  If by vector you mean 1D array, then there's no reason it should be faster than accessing a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

C has no *multidimensional* arrays like in other languages, it called them *multidimensional*   but they are really arrays of arrays.

And C arrays are contiguous.

> (C99, 6.2.5p20) "An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type, called the element type."